# SSIS: How to transfer data from table A to table B and then update table A flag column for each row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ssis

I need to crate a package in SSIS which will selectively transfer data from Table A to table B based on a flag in Table A and after the transfer update the flag in Table A.

Please advice on the approach to this scenario and the different ways in which this can be done effectively.

I would also like to mention that i have never worked on SSIS packages before.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for (i.e. what have you tried; what is the problem (performance?))? The Data Flow Tasks are pretty self explanatory, I think. Source -> Conditional Split (if you read records you don't want) -> SQL Task (for update) -> Destination.

Comment: I don't see a way in which i can update every row of the source table A after data has been transfered/inserted to Table B using DFT. So what i want is after every row transfer, i want to update the flag in that row, is that possible using DFT?

Answer (score 2):

DFT : Source : Select query where Flag filteration

Execute SQL: Update statement with same flag codnition

Comment: The only problem that i see with using Execute SQL task is - what if rows get added to the table after DFT started running? Exec sql task would "mark" them as processed without loading them into table B. I think using a Multicast in combination with SQL Command component and running inside a transaction would solve the problem.

Comment: Using an OLE DB Command invites poor performance.  Use a Data Flow Task followed by an Execute SQL Task as suggested.  Place both in a Sequence Container, and "require" a transaction on the Sequence Container.